# Можно ли сделать константу сразу для нескольких похожих по названию элементов?

Tags: javascript

Допустим на странице может появлятся class-0, class-1, class-2 и так далее. Можно ли как то сделать общую константу? Пытался подставить вместо цифры регулярное выражение любая цифра, но это неработает.
const allclass = document.querySelector('.class-/d');

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[class^=class-]')`, только вы сначала пишете `class-0, class-1...`, а в примере уже выбираете `.myclass-`

Comment: ошибся, исправил

Comment: А зачем делать class-0 class-1 class-2 ? Смысл же классов объеденить группу. А это - непонятное извращение

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, вообще там, на этом сайте таких классов 299 штук. Называются они по другому ну принцип в названии такой. Меняется только цифра.

Comment: Ты не уловил суть моего сообщения

Comment: похоже вам нужен массив либо объект. `var x =[00, 11, 22, 33]; console.log(x[1]); // 11` но в случае с объектами, свойство(содержащийся в нем элемент) не должно начинаться с цифры

Comment: если же речь про кучу +- одинаковых **css селекторов...** если все они применены к одинаковым тегам, селектор самого тега и возьмите. `<hr class='a'><hr class='b'><hr class='c'> <style>hr{color: red}</style>`

Comment: Если нужно спрасить сайт, то вот как идея ```[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter((elem)=>/a/.test(elem.className));``` такой код ищет все элементы у которых в классе есть "a"